# Wordpress / PHP: Get value of variable outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, loops, post

In my WordPress template (that I am developing), I have the header.php and a template part named header-head.php (called in the header.php). At the index.php, I have other template parte named content.php (called in the index.php). I am trying to get a information of the first post of the taxonomy (named feeling) that I created and return the value in the header-head.php.

The content.php code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'feeling');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    //Always check if it's an error before continuing. get_term_link() can be finicky sometimes
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'feeling' );
    if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;
    //We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    $term_return = '<a href="' . $term_link . '">Feeling ' . $term->name . '</a>';
}

if ( has_term( '', 'feeling' ) AND $count == 0 ) {
    $latest_feeling = "<p class='feeling-text'>" . $term_return . "</p>";
    $GLOBALS['feeling_post'] = $latest_feeling;
}
```

The header-head.php code:

```
$feeling_return = $GLOBALS['feeling_post'];
echo $feeling_return;
```

You may have noticed the variable $count, it count the number of posts to check for the first post. I did it in the index.php file and then got the value in the content.php file using $GLOBALS, but now I am not getting...

The index.php loop code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $GLOBALS['count_post'] = $count++; ?>

            <?php
                /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'partials/content', get_post_format() );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php sensibus_paging_nav(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should post the relevant index.php stuff, too.

Comment: One of the main things that we need to know is the order of operations; it seems to me that content.php will be included and processed after header-head.php, so the value you seek may not be available at the time that header-head.php is executed.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins That must be it! But is there any way to call content.php before? I really never thought about it... Thank you!

Comment: There are two possible solutions: First is to consider if you really need the value. Are you sure that displaying this value in the header is the right way to go? If you are sure that you need the value to be available like this, consider making the value a constant in your configuration file and including it as needed.